# Find a specific position in notepad++(postion 4292) That contains anything other than a specific character (N)

Tags: notepad++

I have a rather large flat file that has some data issues. I am trying to find a fast way to determine where those issue lie. Position 4292 should either contain a Y or an N. I need to find all lines that are blank or contain any other character. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You mentioned "position 4292". I don't know what this is. Is it a line 4292, or offset from the start of the file, or something else?

Comment: Its position 4292 on each line, or column 4292 in each line

Comment: Do you want to find complete line, or just that one character that is neither Y nor N? What do you want to do when you find all those, plus all empty lines?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature of regular expressions called "lookbehind" (there is also a complement feature "lookahead", which is not important for us here). You want to find something that is neither Y nor N, and is preceded with 4292 characters starting from the line beginning.

Lookbehind is stated with `(?<=expression)`.
To anchor expression to beginning of the line we use `^expression`.
To repeat something N times we use `expression{N}`.
To find something that is not Y or N we use `[^YN]`.
To find a blank line we use both start and end anchors `^$`

Combining all of these we have the following:

`(?<=^.{4292})[^YN]|^$`

Maybe you have to use number 4291 instead of 4292. Not exactly sure.

If you want to extract all found lines, switch from tab "Find" to tab "Mark" in the same dialog, activate option "Bookmark line", and click "Mark All". A bookmark will be placed on every such line. If you want to copy all those lines, select from the menu Search > Bookmark > Copy Bookmarked Lines. Then paste this to a new file.

This is such elegant solution that this problem looks very much like a test question. But who would teach and test Regex...